# Griddb installation on windows: where to find the file CmakeList.txt

Tags: database, windows, griddb

I am installing griddb on windows as per below link
https://griddb.org/python_client/cmake_build_guide.html

In step 1.3.2 Install python it is mentioned that
Set path for PYTHON_RESOURCE in CmakeList.txt

I am not able to locate CmakeList.txt file. where to find that?

Answer (score 0):

The File CmakeList.txt file is present at below path

\cmake-3.14.5-win64-x64\share\cmake-3.14\Modules\FortranCInterface

Comment: Thanks Prakash for the path. I can find that now.